# Syntax error with creating a recurring booking

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to create a repeated booking with the following code, but I got errors, how would I fix this code?

```
//creates a recurring booking
            if (repeats_check.IsChecked == true)
            {
               DateTime date0=date_picker.SelectedDate;
//Calculates the total number of days between each repeat by multiplying the number of weeks by 7.
                int Rdays1 = Rdays + (Rweeks * 7);
                for (int i = 1; i <= occurences.Value; i++)
                {
                   DateTime Date(i) = Date(i-1).AddDays(Rdays1);
                   DateTime Datei = Datei.AddMonths(Rmonths);

                }

            }
```

Comment: What errors does it report?

Comment: expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit more lost than I thought, actually, as a VB user :) ... it needs a C# tag (I've changed it). Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you wanted to do here:

```
DateTime Date(i) = Date(i-1).AddDays(Rdays1);
DateTime Datei = Datei.AddMonths(Rmonths);
```

It will definitely not work. If it's an array then use Date[i]. But then in first line you don't need type for Date[i]. Can you clarify your code?

EDIT:

Following your explanation:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[occurences.Value+1];
dates[0] = date_picker.SelectedDate;
for (int i = 1; i <= occurences.Value; i++)
  dates[i] = dates[i-1].AddDays(Rdays1).AddMonths(Rmonths);
```

BTW. I've simulated your error, look at this:

[image]

And I get same error: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

mz

Comment: I want to create a repeated booking where Rdays is the number of days it will repeat by, Rweeks is the number of weeks it will repeat by and Rmonths is the number of months it will repeat by.

I have a certain number of occurrences so I have a for loop for the occurrences. I wanted Date(i) to be date with the number from the for loop and Date(i-1) to be the previous date.

So when i=1, Date(1)=Date(0).AddDays(Rdays1)

Comment: In C# notation something(1) doesn't work for arrays, use something[1] but first create it.

Comment: so how would you recommend doing this for my scenario?

Comment: i got the Index was outside the bounds of the array error on this line:   dates[i] = dates[i - 1].AddDays(Rdays1);

Comment: yes, I did not notice you're using <= in loop, just make array bigger by one, I've updated code.

Comment: Yes, it's not working as you've got hidden bug there as well :-) AddDays and AddMonths return new DateTime object. So first operation creates new date and second overwrites it. To fix this, change it to chain. I've changed code.